# how to convert stylus file to scss file for more easy?

Tags: sass, stylus

I have some stylus file and want to convert these to scss, how can I do this for more easy? use regexp, postcss, or other methods?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compile `stylus` in `css`, and to `scss` connect `css`-file.